# Show user specific data using Web API without accessing session variable

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I keep reading that using session variable in Web API is not a good practice and it should be avoided because Web API is RESTful. But then how can you display user specific records from a table?

Consider the scenario where I am displaying data from a table. The data is being displayed using AJAX/JSON for which I have created a controller in Web API. Now this will show all records from table to any user who access that page. What if I want to show only those record which belong to particular user who is viewing page?

Right now what I am doing is, saving user id in cookie on session start and then access that cookie in Web API controller and pass it on to database query. Is this ok?

Thanks

Comment: It is fine to use cookie authentication if your API is for simple situations and not much complexity. Try to make a fixed time persist on the database side.

Comment: What is fixed time persist?

Comment: I expressed myself the wrong way. Make sure you that you have a expiration time on that cookies so the user has to authenticate again.

Comment: I am using Windows authentication so user doesn't have to login.